# How to query SQL Server CDC through JDBC incrementally

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, change-data-capture

I am trying to incrementally read SQL Server CDC changes. 
In my first interval, I query

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_mytable(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_mytable'), " +
  "sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all') ORDER BY __$seqval";
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
```

Now I know that __$start_lsn is an LSN (Log Sequence Number) in binary(10). Although I don't understand how I can read it as a Java type so that I can include it my next query and how should I create my next query where I will like to specify the min_lsn as the last LSN which I processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several options for retrieving the data from the `ResultSet`

Then for creating a new query, look at using a a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). There are several options for setting the data based on the type that you you pulled out of the initial query.